# Spring autowire repository by entity type

Tags: java, spring, reflection

All of my entities implement the interface `IEntity`.

I then created an interface for all repositories like so:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface IRepository<T extends IEntity> extends CrudRepository<T, Long>
```

I have some very generic code that takes in any entity type and needs the repository for that entity type. I'm trying to use spring's `ApplicationContext.getBean(Class<T>)` method to fetch the appropriate repository for the entity passed in like this:

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

IRepository<? extends IEntity> getRepository(final IEntity entity) {
    Class<IRepository<? extends IEntity>> clazz = ???????;
    return context.getBean(clazz);
}
```

How to I tell it what class I need to autowire based on?

Comment: Right now I am using a workaround that relies on the repositories being named correctly using
`Class.forName(packagePrefix + entity.getClass().getSimpleName() + "Repository");`

Comment: The usual way to do this is to extend a generic interface or bean e.g. `public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>`, then `@Autowired MyEntityRepository repository`

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do something a bit more advanced which is more similar to `@Autowired IRepository<T> repository` where if T was a MyEntity, then it would wirte up the MyEntityRepository. But if T was MyOtherEntity, then it would wire up MyOtherEntityRepository

Comment: I doubt that will work due to type erasure; all of the repositories which implement the interface would be candidates for autowiring.